# ViewModel IEnum<> property is returning null  (not binding) when contained in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel that contains a Product type and an IEnumerable< Product > type. I have one main view that displays the ViewModel.Product at the top of the page but then I have a partial view that renders the ViewModel.IEnumerable< Product > data.  On the post the first level product object comes back binded from the ViweModel whereas the ViewModel.IEnumerable< Product > is coming back null.

Of course if I remove the partial view and move the IEnumerable< Product > view to the main View the contents comes back binded fine.  However, I need to put these Enumerable items in a partial view because I plan on updating the contents dynamically with Ajax.

Why is the IEnumerable< Prouduct> property not getting binded when it's placed in a partial view? Thx!

Models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public Product NewProduct { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class BoringStoreContext
{
    public BoringStoreContext()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Sure", Price = (decimal)(1.10) });
        Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Sure2", Price = (decimal)(2.10) });
    }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Views:

Main index.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModelBinding.Models.ProductIndexViewModel

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
</div>

@Html.Partial("_Product", Model.Products)

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
</div>
}
```

Parial View _Product.cshtml:

```
@model List<ViewModelBinding.Models.Product>

@for (int count = 0; count < Model.Count; count++)
{ 
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model[count].ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[count].ID)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model[count].Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[count].Name)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model[count].Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[count].Price)
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BoringStoreContext db = new BoringStoreContext();
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel
        {
            NewProduct = new Product(),
            Products = db.Products
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // work with view model

        return View();
    }
```

}

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code and it works for me; I don't see anything wrong. Might want to debug more or start a fresh project with just your above code to verify.

Comment: @KurtSchindler:  Hi. No, look again at viewModel.Prodcuts at the post. It's null. viewModel.NewProduct comes back fine.  Here's the output from the immediate window to check for viewModel.Products:  viewModel.?viewModel.Products.Count.  viewModel.Prodcucts is in a partial view and that is what the ask is based on...why it's coming back as null.
'viewModel.Products' is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@Html.Partial("_Product", Model.Products)` your input fields do not have correct names. For example instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="Products[0].ID" />
```

you get:

```
<input type="text" name="[0].ID" />
```

Just look at your generated markup and you will see the problem. This comes from the fact that when you use `Html.Partial` the navigational context is not preserved. The input fields names are not prefixed with the name of the collection - `Products` and as a consequence the model binder is not able to bind it correctly. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) to better understand the expected wire format.

I would recommend you using editor templates which preserve the context. So instead of:

```
@Html.Partial("_Product", Model.Products)
```

use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products)
```

and now move your `_Product.cshtml` template to `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Product.cshtml`. Also since the editor template automatically recognizes that the Products property is an `IEnumerable<T>` it will render the template for each item of this collection. So your template should be strongly typed to a single Product and you can get rid of the loop:

```
@model Product
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

Now everything works by convention and it will properly bind.

Comment: One question that I do have is that the intent of the partial view was allow ajax updates so that a new product can be added dynamically to that partial view.  I haven't tested yet but not sure if I can accomplish this with EditorFor (as opposed to a partial view)?